# Savefiledialog from a callback on a server

Tags: silverlight

We have a button that fires a command which goes to the server to do some validation. This is done asynchronously and if the validation is okay (i.e. the user has the correct permission), I want to show the SaveFileDialog.

However, this is not a user initiated action which means calling the SaveFileDialog.ShowDialog() method raises a "Dialog must be user initiated" exception.

Is there any way to make this work the way I want?

To other option is to launch the SaveFileDialog and make the request after the file has been selected. Not ideal but it works.

JD.

Comment: Just my two cents but what we did was to have a popup that indicates the file is being downloaded if s/he has access. Once the file download is completed we will have a 'save' button on the popup that will open the SaveFileDialog.ShowDialog()

Comment: Thanks Johannes, that is an excellent idea. In fact, for our framework your solution would fit in perfectly.
JD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no work around after all it would be a pointless restriction if there were a work around.

I think your alternative design choice make sense.  You might consider using a busy indicator with the message "Validating..." or some such whilst the async validation occurs then do what ever it is you would have done once the asyc operation completes.